# AppleScript does not see sub element of `RenderWidgetHostViewCocoa`, but enabling VoiceOver fixes that. Why?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to automate some routines in MS Teams, but I ran into issue of AppleScript not exposing all of this apps controls.

```
tell application "System Events"
    get entire contents of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of process "Teams"
end tell

Result:
{button 1 of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 2 of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 3 of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events"}
```

It returns close, min and max buttons and that's it.

Accessibility Inspector fails to track individual UI elements either, showing entire window as a `RenderWidgetHostViewCocoa`.

That seemed strange for such a respectable company to not care about ally of its product, so I tried to use VoiceOver (Cmd+F5) and see if it can detect individual ui elements. And it did! It properly announces all highlighted ui elements of Teams.

What is even stranger is that after enabling of VoiceOver my AppleScript managed to return all the elements it did not see before.

```
tell application "System Events"
    get entire contents of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of process "Teams"
end tell
Result:
{UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 2 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of button 2 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", text field 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 4 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 4 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", pop up button 1 of group 4 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 3 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 3 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 1 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 2 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 3 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 3 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 4 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 4 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 5 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 5 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 6 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 6 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 7 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 7 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 7 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 7 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 8 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 8 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 9 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 9 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", checkbox 1 of group 1 of group 9 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 10 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", pop up button 1 of group 10 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of pop up button 1 of group 10 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", static text "Help" of pop up button 1 of group 10 of list 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", pop up button "Chat" of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of pop up button "Chat" of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", static text "Chat" of group 1 of pop up button "Chat" of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of pop up button "Chat" of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 2 of pop up button "Chat" of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 2 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of button 2 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 2 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 2 of group 5 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 1 of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", static text "Have private conversations Sometimes you just want to chat or video call privately one-on-one or with a group." of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", UI element 1 of static text "Have private conversations Sometimes you just want to chat or video call privately one-on-one or with a group." of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", static text "Have private conversations" of UI element 1 of static text "Have private conversations Sometimes you just want to chat or video call privately one-on-one or with a group." of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", UI element 2 of static text "Have private conversations Sometimes you just want to chat or video call privately one-on-one or with a group." of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", static text "Sometimes you just want to chat or video call privately one-on-one or with a group." of UI element 2 of static text "Have private conversations Sometimes you just want to chat or video call privately one-on-one or with a group." of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 1 of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of button 1 of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", static text "Private chat and calling" of button 1 of list 1 of group 6 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 7 of group 5 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 6 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 1 of group 6 of group 2 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 3 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 4 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", group 5 of group 1 of UI element "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 1 of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 2 of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events", button 3 of window "Chat | Microsoft Teams" of application process "Teams" of application "System Events"}
```

What does the VoiceOver do to get access to the sub-elements of a `RenderWidgetHostViewCocoa`? And can it be done from an applescript itself?

Right now I have a simple automation added to enable/disable it ...

```
tell application "System Events"
  key code 96 using command down
  delay 1
  key code 96 using command down
  delay 1
end tell
```

... but it is not pretty, and VoiceOver announces itself every time. :(

Answer (score 2):

MS Teams is an app built on [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), which is a framework that allows native apps to be written as websites. For performance reasons, the control tree is not created unless an accessibility technology is detected (e.g. JAWS on Windows or VoiceOver on macOS).

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/accessibility

At the end of that documentation, they specify a manual override to enable the accessibility tree. I couldn't find a way to do this directly in AppleScript (It doesn't look possible because of this stackoverflow question: [Can't set settable accessibility attribute in AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10511156/1248889)), so I built a tiny cli app to make the call:

https://github.com/JonathanGawrych/set-electron-app-accessible

If you clone the repo and run `make`, then you could turn on MS Team's accessibility by doing:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set pid to unix id of first process whose name is "Teams"
    do shell script "./set-electron-app-accessible " & pid
end tell
```